# Stiff non-linear ODE with free boundary problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages

I use mathematica to solve differential equations and many problems I solve have a free boundary.  In trying to solve the equation I provide below, however, I get the following message:

NDSolve::ndsz: At m == 0.04906081939241271`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

This is the code I am using:

```
param = { α -> 1/2, ζ -> 1/2, μ -> 
1, δ -> .13, σH -> .25, ν -> .01, 
r -> .06, γ -> 1/2, ψ -> 2}; Clear[v, f, d];

GG[mh0_?NumberQ] := Module[{mH = mh0}, Clear[v, f, d];
  f = v[m] /. (NDSolve[{μ + v[m]^2/(
       2 α) + ((α + m^2 ζ) Derivative[1][v][
         m]^2)/(2 α ζ) + 
       v[m] (-r - (m Derivative[1][v][m])/α) + 
       1/2 σH^2 v''[m] == 0, 
     Derivative[1][v][0] == γ + ψ , 
     Derivative[1][v][mH] == γ} /. param, v[m], {m, 0, mH},
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"] // Flatten);
  d[m_?NumberQ] = D[D[f, m], m];
  {d[mH]}]

sol = FindRoot[GG[mH], {mH, 35}]
```

The problem is not the free boundary mH, but rather the gradient of the value function-- in particular, the square taken on the term v'[m] of the ODE.  I would be EXTREMELY grateful to have your feedback on how I can cajole Mathematica to solve my non linear ODE.

Comment: The problem is the `"StartingInitialConditions"` automatically chosen by the shooting method. They probably lead to a singularity. Looks like you have to supply good starting points yourself. Search the docs for "StartingInitialConditions", if that's new to you. Or you could possible reformulate the problem for the finite element method.

Comment: Thanks this was very useful.  I specified initial conditions and it worked out!